# extend AngularJs's angular global object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, typing

I upgraded my typescript version to 3.8.3

my project is written with AngularJS and includes `.js` and `.ts` files.

I have a legacy code that extends the `angular global object` with 2 functions.

```
angular.isUndefinedOrNull = function (val) {
    ...
};
angular.isDefinedAndNotNull = function (val) {
    ...
}
```

after upgrading the typescript version I have got this error message:

```
Property 'isDefinedAndNotNull' does not exist on type 'IAngularStatic'
```

I understand that I need to create an extended interface for `angular` object, but I am struggling with how, everything that I'm trying does not succeed.

tried to add a `global.d.ts` file to the root directory with the following :

```
declare namespace angular {
    interface IAngularStatic {
        isUndefinedOrNull: (any) => boolean;
        isDefinedAndNotNull: (any) => boolean;
    }
}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: how / where is the angular global extended? this can be done more or less, but I've done a lot of migration work and I'd really recommend not doing it this way and instead just writing a utility functions file and importing these functions where they're needed. rip the band aid off now... typescript even has some useful operators for this natively now, the `??` operator specifically

Answer (score 0):

you're close to it but it's like this:

```
import angular from 'angular';

declare module angular {
    interface IAngularStatic {
        isUndefinedOrNull: (any) => boolean;
        isDefinedAndNotNull: (any) => boolean;
    }
}
```

however, I wouldn't recommend this approach and would instead suggest refactoring to use simple imported functions where needed and using newish typescript features like the null coalescence operator `??`